# How can i connect hc-05 or hc-06 bluetooth module to noudemcu lua v0.9

Tags: android, lua, bluetooth

I am trying to connect hc-05 and hc-06 bluetooth module to noudemcu lua v0.9.
I have already tried SoftwareSerial (d2,d3...d5,d6), and serial (rx,tx). 
I have an app on my Android phone that I made in appinventor. 
This app can connect to the device via bluetooth, but no data is being transmitted.

If I load up skatch to arduino nano, everything works as expected.

Does somebody have a working project for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

There are only two pairs of UART pins available in NodeMCU: standard pins and alternate pins (GPIO13 and GPIO15). If you want to use alternative pins, you should switch to use them. Use the command `Serial.swap()` when programming with Arduino firmware and use `uart.alt()` command when programming in lua.